# Turning on Virtual Machine gives this error

Tags: virtual-machines

I am trying to do an assignment for my IOS 110 class.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXNit.png)

The computer I have is Z230 Tower Workstation.
Intel i7 4790 and 16GB RAM

Comment: Did you by chance get the vm from someone/somewhere else

Comment: You should provide more details (what kind of computer, etc...).  You should also try googling this before posting here.

Comment: I did google and no result

Answer (score 3):

You didn't provide very much information, but you ostensibly do not have hardware virtualization support enabled.  You must go to your BIOS (usually hit delete during the boot-up process) and turn on the VT-x feature (for Intel processors) or the AMD-V feature (for AMD processors).  Without knowing what kind of computer you have, there's no other information I can provide.  Depending on your hardware, you might not have this feature available.  Here's a link to more detailed instructions:

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/Virtualization/sect-Virtualization-Troubleshooting-Enabling_Intel_VT_and_AMD_V_virtualization_hardware_extensions_in_BIOS.html

Comment: Its a HP Z230 Worktower Station with i7 4790

Comment: Try the solution and then get back to me.  You are going to be looking for the VT-x feature (make sure it's turned on).

Comment: It's a college computer and I can not access BIOS. We are not allowed

Comment: Then I suggest you speak with the college system administrator about the error, or attempt to complete the lab on your own computer.

Comment: The first line when you sign up here is "Server Fault is for questions about managing information technology systems in a business environment."